# Using Django with the Facebook API for a polling app

Tags: django, facebook-graph-api, polling

I randomly pick two friends of the user and ask him/her to pick who is the better friend. Now all I have is the friend ID which I then have to use to create a poll and store in the database accordingly. Using the Facebook graph API, I have the ID. All I need to do now is to pass it to Django.

I'm new to this so how exactly would I do that? Pass a javascript variable to Django?

Comment: So you use Facebook Javscript SDK to get friends ID through graph API? Your back-end is Django? What exactly you have to store in the database? Just the friend's ID or other profile detail of the friends? Please be precise while asking questions.

Comment: Yes, I use the Facebook Javascript SDK to get friend IDs. My backend is Django and I would like to create a poll each time for a user which asks the user to pick between friend A and friend B (identified by their friend ID's in the database). Depending on which friend is selected, the database is update with a +1 vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options.

At client side using Javascript SDK,

1. Fetch the friends' profile details along with ID.
2. Convert them to JSON.
3. Do a POST request to a django url/view which stores the data in database.

In this way, you don't need to do any graph API queries further from server side. But this won't help you [updating the data at realtime](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). Consider, if one of the friends changing his name in FB, now what is stored in your database becomes obsolete. So, you need to make sure that some thing from client side implemented to do real time update posts to server side.

At server side using any django facebook graph API apps,

1. Get the IDs from client side.
2. Use the fb graph app to fetch the details at server side.
3. Store them in database.

In this way, you could be able to schedule a callback for real time updates. I prefer the second approach as it's always better to burden the server rather than client. And I found this app simple and do what you need. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-facebook-api/0.1.10